# ejs.renderFile keeps logging output to stdout

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a project using Express.JS with EJS as view engine. Whenever I run `ejs.renderFile`, either directly or with `res.render`, the generated function body gets logged to stdout.

It only happens when `NODE_ENV` is set to `debug` but the thing is that another team has a project with the same setup where it doesn't log anything even when they set `NODE_ENV` to `debug`.
I can't find anything different in their project that could account for this and they don't know either because they simply never had to do anything for it to not log.

I can prevent the logging when using `res.renderFile` by specifying the option `debug: false`, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to prevent it when using `res.render`.

Express.JS version: 4.15.2
EJS version: 2.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three ways how this can happen (instead of `true`, any truish value will do):

- `app.set('view options', { debug : true })`
- `app.locals.debug = true`
- `res.render('template', { debug : true })`

The last two will trigger debug logging because AFAIK there is no distinction made between parameters-to-be-rendered and template-engine-options (at least not for EJS).

Comment: I didn't realize that EJS makes no distinction between the data intended for the template and engine options. I thought the options always had to be the third parameter, after the data. I did indeed have a template data property called "debug", which reflected `NODE_ENV === "debug"`. I renamed that and problem solved.

Comment: I'm not sure if the same applies to `renderFile()`, but for `res.render()` there isn't a proper way of passing options, so it looks like a bit of a hack is applied (`data` is treated as both render data _and_ render options).

Comment: From my experimentation I found out that `renderFile()` uses the second parameter as both data and options if the third parameter is not provided (or is a callback function?). If `options` is provided in addition to `data` they're used separately, or at least `options` takes precedence. `res.render()` however expects the third parameter to be `callback` if anything. @robertklep